# How to use Regular expressions to replace a part of string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have little experince in C# and regex, but I need try this this logic:

```
 string replacedText = Regex.Replace(
     "ssdf bonnets sdf sdf sdf ", 
     @"(?i)^(.+ )?(bonnet)(s?)( .+)?$", 
     "$1hood$3$4"
 );
```

The above code was an answer to question in stackoverflow:

**Replacing a part of string while keeping the rest intact?**
instead of detecting just the word (bonnet) I want to replace multiple values for example if it finds "f" or "b" or "s" it will be replaced by "a"?

for example if the input "ahfbsdrts stb"
   the output wll be "ahaaadrta ata"

Comment: Please post some examples of desired input/output. It is hard to tell what you are trying to do from your question alone

Comment: I added one example if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post another option for short code.

Please see http://forums.asp.net/t/1185961.aspx/1

Something like `string temp = Regex.Replace(input, @"[fbs]", "a");`

Comment: This worked fine thank you but still it does not work with Arabic letters I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: it does not worke with Console but it worked fine with the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use multiple calls to String.Replace?

Comment: because not just that letters I need to replace actualy the above is just an example so I can apply the solution to my problem which is replacing arabic letters such as "ء","أ","ؤ" with "?" and so on with all the arabic text until all arabic text tranformed to the oppsite letter in english

Comment: @Iman25 If you are replacing merely *every* occurrence of a *single* character (even if multiple times), then your best approach would just be to use a simple string.Replace (multiple times, as necessary) in place of Regex parsing.

Comment: but I will need to put some conditions in some cases such if "ا" at the beging of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  string input = "ssdf bonnets sdf sdf sdf ";
  string pattern_1 = "f";
  string replacement = "a";
  Regex rgx_1 = new Regex(pattern_1);
  string result = rgx_1.Replace(input, replacement);
  string pattern_2 = "b";
  Regex rgx_2 = new Regex(pattern_2);
  result = rgx_2.Replace(result, replacement);
  string pattern_3 = "s";
  Regex rgx_3 = new Regex(pattern_3);
  result = rgx_3.Replace(result, replacement);
  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
 }
}
```